# Add a new column in df1 based on match between df1 and df2 in r

Tags: r

I have two data sets df1 and df2, which have one column "ID" in common:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c(1:20), Country=c("US"))
df2 <- data.frame(ID=c(1:10), Gender=c("Female","Male"))
```

How can I add another column `"Respondents"=="Yes"` in df1 if the same ID exists in df2 and is "Female"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a join with the second dataset and create the 'Respondents' column by checking if the 'Gender' is 'Female' then label as "Yes" with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
  left_join(df2) %>% 
    mutate(Respondents = case_when(Gender == 'Female' ~ "Yes" )) %>%
    select(-Gender)
```

Comment: Hi akrun, I just want to add a column in df1 instead of adding df1 to df2

Comment: @Bing Just do the assignment i.e `df1 <- df1 %>%..` updated

Comment: Thanks! But I don't want Female in df1. I just want to add a new column based on conditions

Comment: @Bing in that case, you `select` to remove the 'Gender' updated